# Issues related to psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am running EPD python 2.7.3. I have installed psycopg2 by easy_install . But When i try to import the psycopg2, It shows the following error:

```
>>>import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I am runnin mac osx Mountain lion. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work, i installed with  $ sudo apt-get command on Ubuntu. everything work fine.  may try to uninstall the postgresql and reinstall it.

Comment: I have postgres.app installed on my computer. The installation of psycopg2 was ok. But When I try to import it, it gets the error. I do not think it will fix after re-installation.